# Vim: Match spaces at end of line but not lines consisting of a single space

Tags: regex, vim, diff, removing-whitespace

I realise that in vim, I can highlight trailing spaces at the end of a line using

```
match /\s\+$/
```

Now I would like to exclude those lines that contain exactly one space from being matched. How do I go about doing this? (It does not need to be a single line/regex.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match /\(\S\zs\s\+$\)\|\(^\s\{2,}$\)/`

This should work - breaking it down into 2 sections

Part 1 - search for spaces at the end of a line that has other stuff on the line:  `\(\S\zs\s\+$\)`
not a space `\S`,
then start matching `\zs`,
1 or more spaces at the end of the line `\s\+$`

OR match `\|`

Part 2 - Search for more than one space which is the entire line: `\(^\s\{2,}$\)`
start at the beginning of the line `^`
search for at least 2 spaces `\s\{2,}`
at the end of the line `$`

Comment: Yes! Amazing, exactly what I was hoping for, thanks a lot! Also, thank you for the explanation. :)

Comment: Also consider a shorter regular expression: `\(^ $\)\@!\&\s\+$`.

Comment: @ib. - nice, I was playing around with @ and & and couldn't get them working right.

Answer (score 1):

This matches all lines that contain more than one space, leaving out lines that contain one space.

```
match /\s\s\+$/
```

Comment: I love the idea but this will also hide single spaces at the end of regular lines that consist of more than a space.